# Question about generators of the group of characters

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G^*$ be the group of characters of a finite group $G$ and $\phi_1,\cdots , \phi_n$ elements of $G^*$. Is there a criterion to establish if $\phi_1,\cdots , \phi_n$ generate $G^*$?

I would like to say that they generate $G^*$ if and only if $\cap_i \ker(\phi_i)=1$.

One direction is trivial:

Suppose they are generators. Taking $h\neq 1$, there exists $\eta\in G^*$ such that $\eta(h)\neq 1$. However $\eta$ is written as a combination of $\phi_i$ and so if by contradiction  $h\in \cap_i \ker(\phi_i)$, then $\eta(h)=1$.

Maybe does this work for $G$ abelian?

Any suggestions are appreciate

Comment: So just to check, here by "group of characters" you mean the group of morphisms $G\to \mathbb{C}^*$? (Or equivalently $G\to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.)

Comment: @CaptainLama yes exactly 

Comment: It is not true that if $h\neq 1$ then there is $\eta$ such that $\eta(h)\neq 1$. If $h$ is in the derived subgroup $G'=[G,G]$, then $\eta(h)=1$ for any $\eta\in G^*$ since $\eta$ is a morphism to an abelian group. Actually this direction works if and only if the derived subgroup is trivial, since $G'$ is exactly the intersection of the kernels of the characters.

Comment: @CaptainLama thank you very much. And the iff does hold in the Abelian case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$This is a rephrasing of OP's solution.

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, multiplicatively written. We will use (standard) duality arguments.

Consider the bilinear map $G^{*} \times G \to \C^{\star}$ given by $(\chi, g) \mapsto \chi(g)$. For $B \subseteq G$, let $B^{\perp} = \Set{ \chi \in G^{*} : \chi(g) = 1}$, a subgroup of $G^{*}$, and similarly for $B \subseteq G^{*}$.

Note that $B \subseteq B^{\perp\perp}$, and $B \subseteq C$ implies $C^{\perp} \subseteq B^{\perp}$, and thus $B^{\perp\perp} \subseteq C^{\perp\perp}$.

Moreover, if $H \le G$, one has that each character of $H$ can be extended in $\Size{G : H}$ ways to characters of $G$ (see e.g. Theorem 3.4 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/charthy.pdf)). In particular, if one starts with the trivial character of $H$, then this can be extended to all characters of $G/H$ (slight abuse of language here), so that $H^{\perp\perp} = H$. The same argument applies to $H \le G^{*}$.

Let $B \subseteq G^{*}$, and let $\Span{B}$ be the subgroup it generates. From $B \subseteq \Span{B}$ we get $B^{\perp\perp} \subseteq \Span{B}^{\perp\perp} = \Span{B}$. Now $B \subseteq B^{\perp\perp} \le G^{*}$ implies $B^{\perp\perp} = \Span{B}$, since $\Span{B}$ is the smallest subgroup of $G^{*}$ containing $B$.

Finally, if the intersection of all the kernels of the elements of $B \subseteq G^{*}$ is $\Set{1}$, that is, $B^{\perp} = \Set{1}$, then
$$
\Span{B}
=
B^{\perp\perp}
=
\Set{1}^{\perp}
=
G^{*}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much professor 

Answer (score 1):

I answer to my question because maybe I found a solution.

If $G$ is not abelian, then the sentence is not true, as explained by Captain Lama.

Let us suppose $G$ be a finite abelian group.
I want to prove that a set of characters $\phi_1,\cdots \phi_n$ generate $G^*$ if and only if $\cap_i \ker(\phi_i)=1$

The implication $\Longrightarrow$ is already explained in my question and it works because $G$ is a finite abelian group.

Thus consider $\Longleftarrow$

By contradiction $K:= \langle \phi_i \rangle \neq G^*$.

$Lemma$ 1 : (it’s the equivalence of the consequence of Hahn-Banach theorem in the case of Characters of a Group instead of vector spaces)

Let $G$ be a finite abelian  group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then there exists a non trivial character $\chi \in G^*$ such that $\chi_H$ is trivial.

$Lemma$ 2 : (it’s the Equivalent result of when a vector space is reflexive)

Let $ G$ be a finite abelian group. The canonical injection $j\colon G \to G^{**}$ sending $g $ to $j(g)(\phi):=\phi(g)$ is an isomorphism.

By Lemma 1, take a non trivial character $F\in G^{**}$ of $G^*$ such that $F$ is trivial on $K$. By lemma 2, the canonical injection $j$ is surjective and so $F=j(h)$ for some $h\neq 0$.

Then $\phi_i(h)=j(h)(\phi_i)=F(\phi_i)=1$ for each $i$, and so $h\in \cap_i \ker(\phi_i)$.
This is a contradiction.